# 'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: magento, magento2, progressive-web-apps

I am seting up PWA in my local environment, and following https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/ this.

Stuck at  **'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command**  when running **"yarn run build"** command

I have installed babel globally.

I have gone through many blogs but couldn't find the solution.
Any help would be appriciated.

```
$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.15.2
$ yarn workspaces run build
$ echo 'Skipping graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries build...'
'Skipping graphql-cli-validate-magento-pwa-queries build...'
$ concurrently --raw yarn:build:cjs yarn:build:esm
$ BABEL_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps
$ BABEL_ENV=development babel src --out-dir esm --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps
'BABEL_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js build
Directory: D:\wamp\www\mage-pwa\pwa-studio\packages\peregrine
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspaces for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 9):

They are aware of this problem and work to fix it currently:

https://github.com/magento-research/pwa-studio/pull/899

This is the problem with PWA studio `package.json` scripts. They are written for Unix because they rely to set env variable in a Unix-way, e.g. `BABEL_ENV=... command`.

One way to fix these scripts is to use `cross-env` package and change this:

`BABEL_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps`

to this:

`cross-env BABEL_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --root-mode 'upward' --source-maps`

Check `cross-env` docs here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env#usage